# How to bundle a third party library in a Play Framework module?

Tags: java, playframework

The play framework is built around the notion of modules, which allow the segmentation of large applications is specialized/smaller entities.

Problem: I can't get my module to recognize the jars dropped in its `lib/` folder.

Where should 3rd party libraries be dropped in a typical module ? and what is the `src/` folder made for?

**Update**: Everything works as expected, I am blind ! disregard this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that an application which use your module ignores the `lib`  folder? I looked at the akka-module and they do it exactly this way.

Comment: You are right, I am blind and doing way too many things in //

Comment: This isn't working for me.  I have a jar in my lib dir that is not being found when I use the module.  Can you provide more detail on how to get that jar discovered?

Comment: @JamesWard If you use a local module dependency it should just work.

Comment: My problem was that I was running `play deps --sync` and it was deleting my manually installed jars.